# Java HashMap get works but containsKey does not

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to locate a key in a HashMap. I can print the selected key by using 'get'   but when I use 'containsKey' in an if statement, it is not found.

I KNOW the key is present in the Map but it keeps returning false. Any ideas people?

My code:

```
public static boolean checkLowerStructuralSupport(Location location) {

    boolean hasSupport = false;

    Location supportingLocation = new Location(location.getX(), location.getY(), location.getZ() - 1);

    System.out.println(_levels.get(supportingLocation.getZ()).getLevelSites2().get(supportingLocation)); //works

    if (_levels.get(supportingLocation.getZ()).getLevelSites2().containsKey(supportingLocation)) {
        hasSupport = true;
    } else {
        hasSupport = false;
    }

    return hasSupport;
}
```

Here is the code for the Location class:

```
public class Location {

    protected int _x;
    protected int _y;
    protected int _z;

    public Location(int xAxis, int yAxis, int zAxis) {
        this._x = xAxis;
        this._y = yAxis;
        this._z = zAxis;
    }

    public void equals() {
        //not implemented yet
    }

    public void HashCode() {
        //not implemented yet
    }

    public String toString() {
        String locationString = Integer.toString(_x) + Integer.toString(_y) + Integer.toString(_z);
        return locationString;
    }

    public void setX(int XAxis) {
        this._x = XAxis;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this._x;
    }

    public void setY(int YAxis) {
        this._y = YAxis;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this._y;
    }

    public void setZ(int ZAxis) {
        this._z = ZAxis;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return this._z;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running? If not please provide the exact code you're using (I only ask because in another question, what you provided was not representative of your problem, and caused much confusion).

Comment: Also, is this behavior consistent? I.e., get(...) *always* returns something when expected, and containsKey(...) *never* does?

Comment: Are you developing with a JDK that includes the source code? If so, perhaps you should try debugging the code and stepping into the HashMap methods (containsKey and get) to see if you can find any unusually behavior. Don't worry, these methods are terribly complex.

Comment: This is the exact code and no the behaviour is not consistent. In other methods, containsKey works fine.

Comment: Where does your `_levels` come from?  I don't see it declared inside that method.  If it "lives" outside this method, perhaps other code is changing it during execution?

Comment: Use a debugger. It's easier than trying to figure this out.

Comment: -1 for not showing actual code, then fighting about whether you need to properly implement hashCode and equals - these are things that are really not open for discussion - hashmaps don't work if you don't have those two methods properly implemented.

Comment: When did I fight about how it should be implemented? I am a student who is asking for help from people who know more than me and have implemented the recommendations that have been given :s fh

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must ensure that the `Location` class has properly implemented its `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` methods ([documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)). That is, if two `Location` objects are effectively equal, they should share a common hash code and their `equals` method should return `true`.

Comment: @butterchicken: Maybe get() is not using "hashCode" optimization to get the value, while "containsKey" is.

Comment: Is there any more to the Location class than you are showing?  As shown, equals and hashCode have the wrong signatures (and spelling), so if Location inherits from a superclass, then maybe that is defining a broken implementation of either.

get/containsKey (in JDK1.6 at least) look to have equivalent source to me, so I think that something must be affecting your data in the meantime.

Answer (score 5):

As descibed here, you have to override the **equals(Object)** method.

The reason why get(Object) is working is, that HashMap will calculate the Hash for your Location class and returns the Object the hascode points to.

containsKey(Object) calculates the hash key and gets the object the hash is pointed to. The object from the HashMap will compare to the Object you put in. For these comparison the equals method is used.
When you do not override he equals method, true is returned, when the object reference to the same instance.

**From HashMap**

```
/** 
 * Check for equality of non-null reference x and possibly-null y. 
 */
static boolean eq(Object x, Object y) {
    return x == y || x.equals(y);
}
```

**From Object**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
    }
```

From the javadoc of equals

> The equals method for class Object
>   implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on
>   objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method
>   returns true if and only if x and y
>   refer to the same object (x == y has
>   the value true).
>
> **Note that it is generally necessary to
>   override the hashCode method whenever
>   this method is overridden, so as to
>   maintain the general contract for the
>   hashCode method, which states that
>   equal objects must have equal hash
>   codes.**

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure get(...) will compare the key (Location) for equality also, and uses the hash only to locate it quickly (reduce the number of comparisons). How else would it distinguish between multiple objects with the same hash (which is perfectly legal).

Answer (score 2):

In **Location** class, make sure you are overriding **hashCode** and **equals** methods.

If you are, can you post them?

Answer (score 2):

containsKey uses the method equals to compare the param with the entries in the key set. So the Location class needs to have a equals method that is good. The default equals method in java.lang.Object only returns true when both objects are the same object. In this case you probably have 2 different instances that needs to be compared and need a custom equals method.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that will cause this is if the state of `supportingLocation` is somehow being mutated between the `get(...)` call and the `containsKey(...)`.

Assuming the code snippet you posted is the exact code that's causing problems, the only place this could occur is if one of `Location#getZ(...)`, `Location#hashCode()` or `Location#equals(Object)` mutates the state of Location (or the Location constructor, or one of these methods starts a thread that randomly changes the state of the Location instance, but I think we can rule that out).

Could you verify that none of the methods above are changing the state of the `supportingLocation` instance? While I am not familiar with the `Location` class itself, I'd venture to guess that a class like that would ideally be immutable.

Edit:
To clarify, when I say that `Location#getZ()` etc aren't mutating the Location, what I mean is:

```
Location x = new Location(1,2,3);
Location y = new Location(1,2,3);

boolean eq1 = x.equals(y);
int hash1 = x.hashCode();
x.getZ(); // this should *not* mutate the state of x
boolean eq2 = x.equals(y);
int hash2 = x.hashCode();
```

In the end, eq1 should be equal to eq1, and hash1 should be equal to hash2. If this is not the case, getZ() is mutating the state of x (or equals, or hashCode, or worse, those methods are completely off), and will result in the behavior you observed.

Comment: The code I have posted is the exact implementation. The Location class has mutator methods. Cheers.

Comment: Mutation should not matter.  equals and hashCode have not been overridden, so the default versions will be used, and they only look at the pointer, not the state of the object.

Comment: Yup, I agree, my answer was posted before the full Location source code was posted. I'm at a loss to what's wrong now, perhaps a rogue `Map` implementation, or a bug in `getLevelSites2()`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `get()` and `containsKey()` are using the `Location` class's `hashCode()` method.  The `equals()` method isn't called unless there is a hash collision.  (thus, HashMap's get() won't use `equals()` in every situation.)

For your `Location` class, did you by chance happen to implement your own version of `hashCode()`?  The `hashCode()` method should be implemented carefully.  Joshua Bloch described all the details in the book *Effective Java*, portions of which are online...   I'll go find the link to those sample chapters:  [Effective Java Sample Chapters](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/chapters.html).  You want chapter 3.

As I asked in the comment to the question, Where does your `_levels` variable come from? I don't see it declared inside that method and your naming (underscore prefix, are you importing that convention from some other language?) suggests that it "lives" outside this method.  Perhaps other code is changing it during execution?  Please let us know when you solve it; the suspense is killing me.

Comment: I'd think they both use equals(). Keep in mind, it's perfectly legal for two instances of an object to return the `hashCode()`. In fact, it isn't even illegal for all `hashCode()` to simply return the same constant (e.g., 0), just really really sub-optimal.

Comment: No - look in the JDK source: get and containsKey (via getEntry) both check key equality (unless the key identity is the same) in the line:   if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))

Comment: equals will get called during a get if there's a hash collision.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems, your `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods should be consistent and conform to the requirements (as noted elsewhere).

Additionally, hashCode() should **not** rely on mutable members, otherwise your calculated hash code can change, and this affects the internal workings of the `HashMap`. That will reveal itself in an inability to retrieve stuff from `Hash*` collections.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peak at the source code for the HashMap implementation. Both get and containsKey use the hasCode() and equals() methods of your key object.

The only real difference, and as was pointed out, it is a trivial null check, is in the comparisons:

get:

```
((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))
```

containsKey:

```
((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))
```

where e is of type Entry for a HashMap.

So, if you do not have a strong implementations of hashCode() and/or equals() you will have a problem. Additionally, if your keys were mutated (I see that you did not declare the class fields final) you could have an issue.

Take the following example:

```
public class HashMapTest {
    static class KeyCheck {
        int value;
        public KeyCheck(int value) { this.value = value; }
        public void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }
        @Override public int hashCode() { return value; }
        @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return ((KeyCheck)o).value == this.value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<KeyCheck, String> map = new HashMap<KeyCheck, String>();
        KeyCheck k1 = new KeyCheck(5);
        KeyCheck k2 = new KeyCheck(5);

        map.put(k1, "Success");

        System.out.println("Key: " + k1 + " Get: " + map.get(k1) +
                           " Contains: " + map.containsKey(k1));
        System.out.println("Key: " + k2 + " Get: " + map.get(k2) +
                           " Contains: " + map.containsKey(k2));

        k1.setValue(10);

        System.out.println("Key: " + k1 + " Get: " + map.get(k1) +
                           " Contains: " + map.containsKey(k1));
        System.out.println("Key: " + k2 + " Get: " + map.get(k2) +
                           " Contains: " + map.containsKey(k2));
    }
}
```

This will print out:

> Key: HashMapTest$KeyCheck@5 Get: Success Contains: true
>   Key: HashMapTest$KeyCheck@5 Get: Success Contains: true
>   Key: HashMapTest$KeyCheck@a Get: null Contains: false
>   Key: HashMapTest$KeyCheck@5 Get: null Contains: false

As you can see, in this case the mutability caused the hashCode() to change, which ruined everything.

Comment: I don't think that the difference between get and containsKey is significant, because it is only for when key is null, and in that case get has a special case code path (which will already have returned).  Your point about mutating key values is well made though.

Answer (score 0):

i think sometime you need the hash code and sometimes not so i think in this way you can turn of the hash code checking when you want buy changing the hash code for all objects you want to 0

```
public class sample(){
    @JsonIgnore
    private int hashCode = super.hashCode();

    public void setHashCode(int hashCode){
        this.hashCode = hashCode;
    }    

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return this.hashCode;
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final ReflectObject other = (ReflectObject) obj;
        if (this.hashCode != other.hashCode) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```