# HashMap with StringKey problem?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a List of Foo Objects. If a name appears multiple times, I want to do something to the first Item with that name.

```
HashMap<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
for (Foo bar: this.FooList)
{
    if (!map.containsKey(bar.getName()))
    {
        map.put(bar.getName(), bar);
    }
    else
    {
        map.get(bar.getName()).doSomeThing();
    }
}
```

But this is not working, because every name (unique or not) gets thrown in that map. Does the HashMap check only for reference equality and not equality on key objects?

Comment: Are you sure that you have duplicated names?

Comment: 1oo% sure... but the else case is never executed.

Comment: Is `String` in this case a `java.lang.String` or a badly named class with no `equals` or `hashcode`?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104030/java-hashmap-get-works-but-containskey-does-not

Comment: no, it's definitely java.lang.String

Comment: @pjp:  I've never tried doing that.  I always assumed you can't name classes the same as things in java.lang, because everything in java.lang is considered to be in the default namespace.

Comment: @rb: You can use the same names. You'd just need to refer to the type with the package name. E.g. you can create a class called `String` containg as `java.lang.String` member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
    HashMap<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
    for (Foo bar: this.FooList)
    {
        if (!map.containsKey(bar.getName()))
        {
            map.put(bar.getName(), bar);
        }
        else
        {
            Foo foo = map.get(bar.getName());
            if (foo != null)
                foo.doSomeThing();
            map.put(bar.getName(), null);
        }
    }
```

Here's a testbed for it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Example().run();
    }

    private ArrayList<Foo> FooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();

    public void run()
    {
        FooList.add(new Foo("abc", 1));
        FooList.add(new Foo("abc", 2));
        FooList.add(new Foo("def", 3));
        FooList.add(new Foo("abc", 4));
        FooList.add(new Foo("abc", 5));
        FooList.add(new Foo("ghi", 6));
        FooList.add(new Foo("def", 7));

        HashMap<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
        for (Foo bar: this.FooList)
        {
            if (!map.containsKey(bar.getName()))
            {
                map.put(bar.getName(), bar);
            }
            else
            {
                Foo foo = map.get(bar.getName());
                if (foo != null)
                    foo.doSomeThing();
                map.put(bar.getName(), null);
            }
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(String name, int i)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.i = i;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void doSomeThing()
        {
            System.out.println(getName() + " " + i);
        }

        private String name;
        private int i;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
abc 1
def 3
```

Comment: Why not use the interface type `Map<String,Foo>` in your declaration?

Comment: What are the cases for `foo` being `null` in the `else` case. I'd expect a `NullPointerException` in `bar.getName()` if `bar` was `null`. The only other reasons would be inconsistent `Map.get()` and `Map.containsKey()` methods unless the map is being modified by multiple threads.

Comment: pjp: No reason for using HashMap: I just copied his code. You're right that it could be changed to Map.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... if Foo implements `equals()` so that it only checks name, you could always do something like this:

```
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<Foo>();
for (Foo bar: this.FooList)
{
    if (!set.add(bar)) {
       bar.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Which works because `set.add(bar)` will run `bar.equals` against every element already in the set, and return false if any of them are equal.

Edit: Since this is a HashSet, you should also implement `hashCode()`.  Heck, you should always implement `hashCode()` if you're overriding `equals` anyway.

Comment: A couple of caveats: it needs to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`; the equality checks must depend only on the `name` property.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned `hashCode()` since this is a `HashSet`.  Whoops.  I kind of assumed that if `equals()` was implemented, it would just be on name, which is kind of a naive assumption.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? The code adds the `Foo` if it hasn't been encountered before, and invokes an action on the `Foo` if it has been encountered before. What were you expecting it to do?

To answer your question at the end, `HashMap` relies on the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the key objects.

**UPDATE**: Are you trying to invoke `doSomeThing` *only* on repeated `Foo`s? If the `name` property of a `Foo` defines it's identity (and you properly implemented `hashCode()` and `equals()`) you should use [R. Bemrose's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861658/hashmap-with-stringkey-problem/1861914#1861914). If `name` is *not* a unique property of `Foo`s, the following code might help:

```
final Map<String, Foo> firstFooByName = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
final List<String> dupeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (final Foo foo: myFoos) {
    final String fooName = foo.getName();
    if (!firstFooByName.containsKey(fooName)) {
        firstFooByName.add(fooName)
    } else {
        dupeNames.add(fooName);
    }
}

for (final String fooName : dupeNames) {
    firstFooByName.get(fooName).doSomeThing();
}
```

Comment: The call to `Map#containsKey()` is unnecessary here. Just call `Map#put()` and test the return value against null -- assuming that none of the values in the map are permitted to be null. That saves one hash lookup, bucket traversal, and key comparison per item, as the same work done by `containsKey()` must be done to prepare for `put()`.

Comment: I think `containsKey` is the most straightforward way to capture the programmer's intent, and it doesn't rely on implicit constraints on the allowed values (since some `Map` implementations allow `null` values). Unless I had profiler output proving this was a hotspot, I wouldn't waste my time "optimizing" it into a less clear version.

Comment: With more time to reflect, my suggestion above is inappropriate. I was thinking of `Set#add()` and `ConcurrentMap#putIfAbsent()`, both of which are idempotent. The original question here wanted to add the item to the map only if the key didn't yet exist; my misguided proposal above would mistakenly replace the value associated with a given key, only after which the caller could detect that the key had been present before. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap uses the .equals() method on the key object.

Comment: and equals for String checks the value equality rather than the reference equality, so things *should* work as expected.