# java HashMap containsKey is returning false though key is present

Tags: java

I am using a HashMap data structure to store a SqMatrix (square matrix), where the key is of type MatrixIndex (which contains row and col) and the value is of type Integer.

But when I am getting false as output of "if (mat.containsKey(key))" though the HashMap has the corresponding key in it.

The main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random generator = new Random();
    int val = 0;
    Types.MatrixIndex key, key1;
    int matSz = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(10));
    Types.SqMatrix mat = new Types().new SqMatrix(matSz); //matSz*matSz elements
    //HashMap<Types.MatrixIndex,Integer> hMap= new HashMap<Types.MatrixIndex,Integer>(10);
    for (int r=0; r<matSz; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<matSz; c++) {
            if (r<c) {
                val = generator.nextInt(2) > 0? -1 : val;
                key =(new Types()).new MatrixIndex(r, c);
                key1 = (new Types()).new MatrixIndex(c, r);
                mat.put(key, val);
                mat.put(key1, val);
                generator.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }
    }

    for (int r=0; r<matSz; r++) {
        val = 0;
        for (int c=0; c<matSz; c++) {
            if (r!=c) {
                key = (new Types()).new MatrixIndex(r, c);
                if (mat.containsKey(key)) {
                    val = val + mat.get(key);
                }

            }
        }
        key1 = (new Types()).new MatrixIndex(r, r);
        mat.put(key1, val);
    }
```

Do anybody have an idea on why the containsKey is returning false though it is present in the HashMap?

Thanks in advance,

Somnath

Comment: The _accepted_ answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104030/java-hashmap-get-works-but-containskey-does-not might help as I suspect that you haven't implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` for the `MatrixIndex` class

Comment: I don't have any links to accept the answer. Any clues how to accept any reply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea what `MatrixIndex` is, but if it's hashcode implementation isn't overridden, then every instance of `MatrixIndex` has it's own hashcode, and is considered unique.  Therefore, you can't pass in a new instance of MatrixIndex to do a `containsKey()` check.

If you want that exact code snippet to work, you need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in your MatrixIndex class, and make it so that it always creates a reproducible, unique value for that class.

If you haven't done this before, definitely read up on overriding these two methods.  A quick search will bring up a great deal of help.  If you can add new libraries to your project, look at: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks for providing the links. Will ahve a look and let know.

Answer (score 4):

Have you (correctly) defined `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `MatrixIndex` class?

Comment: Here is the implementation of MatrixIndex class:
    
     public class MatrixIndex implements Comparable<MatrixIndex> {
  public int row;
  public int col;
  //...constructors, getters, setters, etc ...

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MatrixIndex o) throws ClassCastException {
   //... implementation
  }
  public boolean equals(MatrixIndex mI) {
   if (mI.getrow() == this.getrow() && mI.getcol() == this.getcol())
    return true;
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: I have not added hashCode(). What is that required for and how to implement that ?

Comment: @somnathchakrabarti, that implementation of `equals()` is definitely wrong.  You _must_ accept an `Object` argument to `equals`.  (And you still need to implement `hashCode`.)

Comment: Yes, but in my case the key Object type is MatrixIndex. So I have overridden the equals method in MatrixIndex and have passed MatrixIndex as parameter, not Object. Why it should be Object?

Comment: The method you have written doesn't override the `equals()` method from `Object`, so is never called. Plus it doesn't obey the contract of `equals()` (for example, passing it `null` will result in a `NullPointerException`). I would have your IDE write both the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for you, if I were you.

Comment: Will this equals code work ?public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (o == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
   }
   if (o instanceof MatrixIndex && this != o) {
    if (((MatrixIndex) o).getrow() == this.getrow() && ((MatrixIndex) o).getcol() == this.getcol())
     return true;
   }
   
   return false;
  }

Answer (score 3):

For `containsKey()` to succeed, the two objects (the one you test and the one found in the Map's keys) MUST have the same `hashCode()` (for non-null objects) AND `equals()` MUST [symmetrically] succeed for them.

> `containsKey()` *"returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)). (There can be at most one such mapping.)"* ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)).

Comment: Yes I have seen the javadocs and only after then I implemented the equals method in MatrixIndex class.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you forgot to override `MatrixIndex.hashCode()` and/or `MatrixIndex.equals()`. The default versions inherited from `Object` class compare object identity, not the objects' contents and will not do what you might be expecting.

Comment: Kosmulski I have posted the equals implementation in the comment. But'm not sure about the hashCode implementation. What can be good hashCode functions? Because I guess that is why the containsKey is still returning false

Comment: I can't find the code for `hashCode()` that you mention. However, most important thing is that if two object instances are equal according to `equals()`, they must return the same hash code, too (not necessarily the other way around). If you have a row and column in the `MatrixIndex`, you could start with `hashCode()` returning their sum or row+N*col where N is a relatively large prime number.